# Trying to validate the complete loading of a page in selenium python through a VM

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, gcc3

I am trying to run a simple selenium automation script (which just loads up google ,searches for youtube and hits the search button) through a virtual machine.So when i set up the options/parameters as shown in the code below (even setting headless mode on), this is what i have:
#Beginning of code

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display   
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary  
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities.  
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

display =Display(visible=0, size=(1024,768))  
display.start()  
options = Options()  
options.headless = False  
caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX  
caps['marionette'] = False  
binary = FirefoxBinary('/home/a-user/Al/firefox/firefox')  
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary= binary, options = options, capabilities= caps,executable_path=r"/home/a-user/Al/firefox/geckodriver")  
browser.get('https://www.google.com')  
browser.find_element_by_name('q').send_keys("Youtube")
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/center/input[1]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)  
print("Headless Firefox Initialized")  
browser.close()  
display.stop()
```

#End of code

But when i try to run it, it shows:
---Beginning of error message ----

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
 File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
   browser.find_element_by_name('q').send_keys("Youtube")  
 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 496, in find_element_by_name
   return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)    
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
   'value': value})['value']    
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
   self.error_handler.check_response(response)   
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
   raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)    
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"q"}
Stacktrace:      
at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///tmp/tmpG1qHlX/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:11885)  
at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///tmp/tmpG1qHlX/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:11894)      
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/k(file:///tmp/tmpG1qHlX/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:13395)   
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpG1qHlX/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:13400)    
at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpG1qHlX/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:13342)
```

I was wondering if theres any way I can make sure the page gets loaded properly, then continue with the automated interaction with the elements.Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium - wait until element is present, visible and interactable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"q"}` because your `driver` is not able to find the element with `name = 'q'` might be because the page is not loaded fully. Refer the below code and make changes in your code accordingly.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
action = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
G_Search = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='q']")))
action.move_to_element(G_Search).send_keys("Youtube").send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

Comment: Hey i tried your approach and im getting an error.                                                  
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 24, in <module>
   G_Search = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='q']")))
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
   raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)